# TortoiseSVN Foreign Repository Copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, vendor-branch

I have been reading up on [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) with subversion.  I'm not very comfortable with the subversion command line and I have been using TortoiseSVN and Subclipse as SVN clients on my Windows 7 box.

In the Vendor Branches documentation for subversion, they discuss doing a "foreign repository copy", but I have not been able to find how to do this with TortoiseSVN.  When I have searched the internet for how to do this with TortoiseSVN, I found articles suggesting using `svn:externals` instead.  The documentation for Vendor Branches does not say to use `svn:externals` and instead says to use a foreign repository copy.

Does anyone know how I can do such a copy with TortoiseSVN?  If it is not possible, would `svn:externals` give me the same result?

**EDIT:**

Here is my workflow:

1. I created a new root-level folder in my repository called `vendor`.  This is a sibling of `trunk`.
2. I checked out `myrepo/vendor` to a new working copy.
3. I attempted to merge `two different trees` using TortoiseSVN from `myvendorrepo/trunk` to `myrepo/vendor`.  This returned an error telling me that `myvendorrepo/trunk` must be in the same repository as `myrepo/vendor`.

The Vendor Branch documentation specifically talks about a `foreign repository copy`, but it does not seem to be possible with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Erm, it mentions it specifically: _" If the third-party information is maintained in a Subversion repository, you could also use Subversion's externals definitions to effectively “pin down” specific versions of that information to some location in your own working copy (see the section called “Externals Definitions”)."_ Then again, you can simply merge 2 different trees in Tortoise to a working copy dir, where does your attempt to do this fail?

Comment: I was trying to do the copy with branch/tag in TortoiseSVN to pull another tree into my working copy.  I didn't try merge.  I interpreted the part about svn:externals to mean that I could either use those or a Vendor Branch.  Can I use externals to get the original unmodified code from the other repository and then create a branch of that in my trunk for my local customizations?

Comment: No, `externals` would only help if you plan _no_ modifications in the code itself. Use that copy & merging of branches to be able to modify it, but also keep the possibility to merge new features / versions of the vendor to yours. Tortoise can do everything that svn manual tells you about. Could you provide a step-by-step in an edit of your question on what you do _exactly_ following the manual, so we can see where it goes haywire?

Comment: @Wrikken - I have listed my steps in an edit to the original post.  I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Aha, you omitted the  important first step indeed: the `svn copy` into that folder of the vendor. Quite easy from the command line, but how to get the TortoiseSVN GUI to do it... I must admit I don't work with Windows, so I'll check it out on a co-workers PC tomorrow, but if I know Tortoise a little, I guess: check out the the vendor SVN into a _different_ folder, right-click & drag to the vendor folder in _your_ checkout. Do you get the `SVN Copy` option, and does it work?

Comment: The "merge two different trees" part only becomes interesting when the 3rd party updates something you want to merge into your vendor dir (when you already changed some stuff there yourself)

Comment: TortoiseSVN does have `SVN Copy` via the `branch/tag` GUI.  I just tried to use that to copy from one repo to another, but it looks like it won't let me specify a destination URL outside the source repo.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

1. "foreign repository copy" can't be done with TortoiseSVN (or any other *SVN-client*, it's task /part of/) **repository management**). And it's usable only if upstream code can't be reached by SVN-client (not versioned at all, stored in SCM, which SVN-client doesn't understand)
2. You misunderstood and misused "2-URL merge" (read `svn help merge`) - this type of merge not used in Vendor Branching, used by different way and for different goals: `svn merge URL1 URL2` will merge into **WC of URL3** independent parallel changes from URL1+URL2

### "Foreign Copy" and Externals Vendor Branching in Sample

Let's imagine:

- External code placed in `VENDOR/PATH/TO/LIBRARY`
- Our **copy** of upstream code - in `MY/VENDORS/VENDOR/LIBRARY` (additional intermediate /VENDORS node is workpiece for the future, when more than 1 vendor may appear)
- Local work happen in `MY/trunk`

**"Foreign Copy"-style**

- ask SVN-admin, who have access to repository filesystem, create dump of full `VENDOR` repository with `svnadmin dump` and transmit dump to you, after it filter only `/PATH/TO/LIBRARY` node with `svndumpfilter`

  - another way is using `svnrdump URL`, which have some benefits: you can dump any remote repository, for which you have read-access, you can dump only part of repository (and eliminate svndumpfilter headache) - `svnrdump dump VENDOR/PATH/TO/LIBRARY > dumpfile`
- prepared (by any way) dump haveto be loaded into `MY` repository: `svnadmin load /PATH/TO/MY < dumpfile` with some additions:

  - because it's dump from another repo, `--ignore-uuid` option (in case of not-empty `MY`) not needed, but may be used for safety
  - because we want to change mount-point of directory from `/PATH/TO/LIBRARY` to `/VENDORS/VENDOR/LIBRARY` additional option `--parent-dir /VENDORS/VENDOR/` is **a must** (TBT!!! I write parent spec from memory)

After these operations you'll have node in your local repository, which is exact copy of remote node, but not related toremote by any way: you have to monitor remote changes and sync  with your copy by hand (`svn up VENDOR/PATH/TO/LIBRARY` in separate WC, copy changes to your WC, commit changes)

**Externals-style**

- Create physical node `/VENDORS/VENDOR/` in `MY` repository (`svn mkdir --parents /VENDORS/VENDOR`)
- define LIBRARY subdirectory of /VENDORS/VENDOR/ as externals (with or without PEG-revision in URL, as you prefer - without will be easier to maintain updates /zero operation/, but harder /impossible/ to resore older, historical state of your repository, with PEG you have to maintain actuality of link by hand /edit PEG-revision, when needed/, but history is stored always correctly automatically), mapped to VENDOR/PATH/TO/LIBRARY

For both styles integration of upstream to your code will be just periodical merge /VENDORS/VENDOR/LIBRARY to trunk

**PS**: for externals-syle first creating initial snapshot in trunk (in case of empty trunk) and first merge to trunk may be troublesome and not obvious. AFAICR, you will not be able to merge /VENDORS/VENDOR/LIBRARY to empty trunk (and `svn copy` also ): you'll get (can't recall text) error and no merge|copy at all. Can't reference to The Right Way, but I just copy filesin Working Copy from vendor branch to trunk and commit trunk in order to have BASE and in this case in first merge (and only first) of LIBRARY to trunk in order to merge unrelated (for Subversion) nodes add `--ignore-ancestry` option: later trunk and LIBRARY **are already related**